# Relationship of Dielectric constant with ionic bond

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, ionic-compounds

How is dielectric constant related to formation of ionic bond?

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks. But chemistry and biology you cant just separate out.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably referring to Coulomb's Law:

$${F\propto \frac{q_1 q_2}{d^2 \epsilon }}$$

This law, that you probably already met in physics, applies to chemistry and ionic bonds, since they are all characterized by electrostatic interactions.

You see that the strenght of a ionic bond is directly proportional to the product of the charges on the ions, inversely proportional to the square of their distance, and **inversely proportional** to the **dielectric constant** of the solvent. In vacuum, the dielectric constant is $\epsilon = 1$.

Otherwise, when the ions are in a solvent, the dielectric constant is associated to the solvent in use (you can find appropriate charts online).